# Static properties (specifically name/displayName) for lazy-loaded component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, lazy-loading

In a React TypeScript project I am rendering a list of menu items, some of which are initially hidden (until the screen size changes). We are using React.lazy to load the menu items that are not revealed until the user changes the screen width. We generate an array of menu items that should be currently visible and render those, some of which are lazy-loaded.

```
const MyMenuItem = React.lazy(
  () => import('../MenuItems/MyMenuItem'),
);
```

I want to give each menu item a unique key (so that I can render it in a list) and I wanted to use `Component.displayName` to do that. When I try to add displayName to the lazy loaded result like this:

```
NewFolderMenuItem.displayName = 'NewFolder'
```

I get this TS warning:

> Property 'displayName' does not exist on type
> 'LazyExoticComponent<(props: MenuItemProps) => Element>'.

I can cast the result of the lazy load as a 'non-exotic' component, but it seems like something I shouldn't ignore because there is this comment in the types for `ExoticComponent`:

> We don't just use ComponentType or SFC types because you are not
> supposed to attach statics to this object, but rather to the original
> function.

I interpret this as saying the displayName should only be attached to the component itself (the one being lazy loaded), but if I do that displayName is not available on the lazy loaded component at runtime (it logs as undefined).

Any ideas what I should be doing and if it's OK to just cast this to a 'normal' component? And why would adding a static prop to the ExoticComponent be such a concern as to disallow it like this?